# How to get min and max values and corresponding ids in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table called product with 3 fields:

```
prod_id  price  pname
1        100    abc
2        200    bbc
3        300    cbc
```

I want to get data of min and max in one row, i.e.:

```
 minprice  prod_id1   maxprice   prod_id2
 100       1          300        3
```

I tried with the following query but not able to find the exact result(if i have more data)

```
SELECT s1.prod_id as prod_id1, 
       s2.prod_id as prod_id2, 
       min(s1.price) as minprice,
       max(s2.price) as maxprice 
FROM product s1
INNER JOIN product s2 ON s1.prod_id = s2.prod_id
```

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two (or more) products with the same max price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select X.id as prod_id1, minprice, Y.id as prod_id2, maxprice
from
(
select id, price as minprice from tablename
where price =(select min(price) from tablename b)
)X cross join
(
select id, price as maxprice from tablename
where price =(select max(price) from tablename c)
)Y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    pmin.price AS minprice, 
    pmin.prod_id AS minprice_prodid,
    pmax.price AS maxprice,
    pmax.prod_id AS maxprice_prodid
FROM (
    SELECT prod_id, price FROM product ORDER BY price LIMIT 1
) pmin
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT prod_id, price FROM product ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1
) pmax
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s1.prod_id as prod_id1, 
       s2.prod_id as prod_id2, 
       s1.price as maxprice,
       s2.price as minprice 
FROM products s1
INNER JOIN products s2 ON s1.price > s2.price
order by s1.price desc, s2.price asc
limit 1
```

#### [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5TDDAvD7vHWwiccArcWZ6n/2)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm not able to get the result, as I have nearly 8000 rows, with the inner join like products s2 ON s1.price > s2.price taking too long to execute.

Comment: If you add an index on the `price` column  it should be really fast.